# width binding in a window with zk

Tags: java, data-binding, window, zk

I have a window like:

```
<window id="camp" border="0" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" 
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.app.viewModel.cpp.MainCpp')"
        >
        <grid>
            <rows>
                <row>
                    <include src="/com.app.web.menu/north.zul" />
                </row>
            </rows>
        </grid>
        .
        . 
        .

</window>
```

And i need spicify a width to the Window, but i need the width depending of a number in my model.

```
 public class MainCpp {
 int num = mmDAO.getnum();
  //Getter and Setter
 //Some Methods
   .
   .
   .
 }
```

Then i need the `width = "num px"` of my window camp;

When my view is open,

How can i do it?

Comment: From http://forum.zkoss.org/question/89742/width-binding-in-window/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a getter to your ViewModel like this:

```
public String getWindowWidth() {
  return  "123px";
}
```

Then bind it in your View:

```
<window width="@load(vm.windowWidth)">
```

Also, you need to use `@NotifyChange` or `@DependsOn` annotation depending on what influences your window width.